# Is there a way to install i386 packages w/ it's i386 dependencies?

Tags: 11.10, software-center, multiarch

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit and I wish to install the CAD application DraftSight, which as of now only come in a 32-bit .deb file.

I have installed this with some success before, but since 11.10 supports multiarch I would like to install the i386 versions of DraftSights dependencies. Ubuntu Software Center cannot handle the file, nor gdebi-gtk ('wrong architecture'). I can use dpkg with --force-architecture --force depends but there's A LOT of dependencies which I need to manually install afterward. Is there a way to automatically install these? Or semi-automatically with a script of some sort? (I'm thinking something along the lines of extracting the dependencies and adding :i386 and then feed that to apt-get or something...)

Below is the output of dpkg-deb --info of the package in question.

```
Package: dassault-systemes-draftsight
 Version: 2011.7.1198
 Section: applications
 Priority: extra
 Architecture: i386
 Pre-Depends: libexpat1 (>=2.0.1-4), libglib2.0-0 (>=2.22.3-0), libpcre3 (>=7.8-3), libselinux1 (>=2.0.85-2), zlib1g (>=1:1.2.3.3.dfsg-13), libc6 (>=2.10.1-0), libx11-6 (>=2:1.2.2-1), libxau6 (>=1:1.0.4-2), libxcomposite1 (>=1:0.4.0-4), libxcursor1 (>=1:1.1.9-1build1), libxdamage1 (>=1:1.1.1-4), libxdmcp6 (>=1:1.0.2-3), libxext6 (>=2:1.0.99.1-0), libxfixes3 (>=1:4.0.3-2build1), libxi6 (>=2:1.2.1-2), libxinerama1 (>=2:1.0.3-2), libxrandr2 (>=2:1.3.0-2), libxrender1 (>=1:0.9.4-2), libatk1.0-0 (>=1.28.0-0), libcairo2 (>=1.8.8-2), libdirectfb-extra (>=1.2.7-2), libfontconfig1 (>=2.6.0-1), libfreetype6 (>=2.3.9-5), libgtk2.0-0 (>=2.18.3-1), libpango1.0-0 (>=1.26.0-1), libpixman-1-0 (>=0.14.0-1), libpng12-0 (>=1.2.37-1), libxcb-render-util0 (>=0.3.6-1), libxcb-render0 (>=1.4-1), libxcb1 (>=1.4-1), debconf (>= 1.1) | debconf-2.0
 Depends: libcomerr2 (>=1.41.9-1), libdbus-1-3 (>=1.2.16-0), libexpat1 (>=2.0.1-4), libgcc1 (>=1:4.4.1-4), libgcrypt11 (>=1.4.4-2), libglib2.0-0 (>=2.22.3-0), libgpg-error0 (>=1.6-1), libkeyutils1 (>=1.2-10), libpcre3 (>=7.8-3), libuuid1 (>=2.16-1), zlib1g (>=1:1.2.3.3.dfsg-13), libc6 (>=2.10.1-0), libgl1-mesa-glx (>=7.6.0-1), libglu1-mesa (>=7.6.0-1), libice6 (>=2:1.0.5-1), libsm6 (>=2:1.1.0-2), libx11-6 (>=2:1.2.2-1), libxau6 (>=1:1.0.4-2), libxdamage1 (>=1:1.1.1-4), libxdmcp6 (>=1:1.0.2-3), libxext6 (>=2:1.0.99.1-0), libxfixes3 (>=1:4.0.3-2build1), libxrender1 (>=1:0.9.4-2), libxt6 (>=1:1.0.5-3), libxxf86vm1 (>=1:1.0.2-1), libaudio2 (>=1.9.2-1), libavahi-client3 (>=0.6.25-1), libavahi-common3 (>=0.6.25-1), libcups2 (>=1.4.1-5), libdrm2 (>=2.4.14-1), libfontconfig1 (>=2.6.0-1), libgnutls26 (>=2.8.3-2), libgssapi-krb5-2 (>=1.7dfsg~beta3-1), libk5crypto3 (>=1.7dfsg~beta3-1), libkrb5-3 (>=1.7dfsg~beta3-1), libkrb5support0 (>=1.7dfsg~beta3-1), libstdc++6 (>=4.4.1-4), libtasn1-3 (>=2.2-1), libxcb1 (>=1.4-1), sendmail
 Installed-Size: 284948
 Maintainer: Dassault Systemes <CrashReports@DraftSight.com>
 Homepage: www.3ds.com
 Description: With DraftSight, you can easily create professional CAD drawings. Supported file formats are DWT, DXF and DWG.
```

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get install -f` after dpkg install. Most of the time this tends to resolve dependency errors ?

Comment: If I install DraftSight with dpkg -i --force-architecture --force-depends and then run sudo apt-get install -f, the solution is to remove DraftSight. It's considered to be a broken package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 12.04, gdebi will install i386 packages on amd64, but it doesn't on oneiric.

Also, on oneiric, `libxcb-render-util0` isn't available. (It was moved to a separate package, which was only added in precise.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [Gdebi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GDebi) is the tool you're searching for. Although it uses local packages for instalation

Comment: Nope, already tried Gdebi and it won't install, due to "Wrong architecture".